# IOS open an application from browser, and after processing send response back to browser

Tags: ios, xcode, deep-linking, twebbrowser

I want a technical help about my website and mobile application communication.
The flow is user will press checkout from the web, and it will redirect to mobile applicaiton on IOS. The application will take the payment and send the response back to Webpage opened in safari.

I have explored some optios like Deep linking and back linking but the issue is In deep linking we can transfer some data to mobile app but we cannot take some response data back on webpage. and the same is with Back linking.

please note that if I open the webpage again using open url method It will open a new tab, but I want to redirect to same page on safari with some response string.

Pleaes note that the platform is IOS, and the communication will be between webbrowser and IOS native Mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out the [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) documentation. It should support your use case.

When checking out, redirect the user to a URL you control that matches your schema, then iOS will redirect to your app, and when you wish to go back to the browser, simply open a link back to your site.

Comment: open a link will open in new tab on safari. I want to go to same tab also. is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @TalaT Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: TalaT, @Anju did you guys get solution for problem?